# Connection to MS SQL Server through Intellij

Tags: sql-server, intellij-idea

I have a bigger project at in which I cant connect to a MS SQL Server. To test things out I moved to a different PC and set up a dummy SQL Server Database to see whether I can connect in this minimal sceneario or not.
I am using the integrated function of Intellij "View - Tool Windows - Database".

Sadly I still can't connect.
The Server Name is PC\SQLEXPRESS. The database name is cbr.

In the "Data Sources and Drivers" I selected the default connection type with the SQL Server Drivers. Host is PC ans Instance is SQLEXPRESS. The Database name is cbr. The URL generated through these Infos seems fine: jdbc:sqlserver://PC\SQLEXPRESS;database=cbr

When I test the connection with using Authentication method "Windows credentials" (integrated Security) I get the following error:
The specified database user/password combination is rejected: [08S01] Error connecting to host "PC", named instance "sqlexpress". Error: "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out". Verify the server and instance names, and ensure that UDP traffic on port 1434 is not blocked by a firewall. For SQL Server 2005 or later, verify that the SQL Server Browser service is running on the host.

When I test the connection with Username & password with the corresponding rights, I get the same error only without the first sentence.

If the problem is firewall related, why am i facing it on different PCs and different Databases?

Comment: could you try the second option mentioned in this document which specifies the instance name? https://support.tibco.com/s/article/JDBC-URL-to-connect-to-SQL-Server-with-instance

Comment: To use an instance name, you need to have SQL Browser Service running, and port 1434 needs to be open on *the server*, as well as the actual port for the instance. Or you can set a static port, and use connect directly over that without an instance name.

Comment: The example in the link would lead to: jdbc:sqlserver://PC;instanceName=SQLEXPRESS:1433;databaseName=cbr. With User & Password and Ingerated Security I get the exact same errors

Comment: @charlieface The ports 1433 and 1444 are open. The start type of the Server Browser Service was "deactivated".  I changed it to automatic and will now double check

Comment: The service is now running and I created inbound rules for ports 1433 and 1434. Still I get the same errors on two different PC trying to connect to local MS SQL Databases.

Comment: Is the instance actually a named instance of `SQLEXPRESS` and have you set a static port for it? Or is it a default instance, in which case you need `jdbc:sqlserver://PC;database=cbr`

Comment: It works now! Without the static port. What I did is follow your advices as well as following the steps here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/db-tutorial-connecting-to-ms-sql-server.html#connect-by-using-windows-domain-authentication. The connection String that worked is jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://PC:1433;instance=SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=cbr; by using the SQL Server jTds Driver. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 0):

I had to follow the steps in this tutorial as well as using the jTds driver: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/db-tutorial-connecting-to-ms-sql-server.html#connect-by-using-windows-domain-authentication

jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://PC:1433;instance=SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=cbr;